# how to do authorization on a nested route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a nested route like this:

```
Route::get('/products/{product}/auctions/create', [AuctionController::class, 'create']);
```

All it does is it sets an auction on a given product. A Product - hasMany - Auctions.

AuctionPolicy to be invoked to authorize actions on an Auction instance:

```
// App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider
protected $policies = [
   Auction::class => AuctionPolicy::class
]
```

AutionPolicy:

```
public function create(User $user, Product $product) // <-- where do I get this $product from?
{
   if( $product->user_id === $user->id ) {
       return $product->canCreateNewAuction();
   }
   return false;
}
```

AuctionController:

```
public function create(Request $request, Product $product)
{
   $this->authorize('create', Auction::class);
}
```

It throws an Exception: `AuctionPolicy::create` expects two params, only one passed.

How do I pass `$product` to `AuctionPolicy::create` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel allows to pass additional data to policies.

[Supply Additional Context](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#supplying-additional-context)

In the `->authorize` method, instead of passing Auction class string, we can also pass an array with additional data.

In this example, we want to be able to pass `$product` to the invoked Auction Policy:

```
$this->authorize('create', [Auction::class, $product]);
```

The first item of this array specifies which Policy (`Auction::class => AuctionPolicy::class`) to invoke and rest are additional data.

It doesn't have to be a class string, it could also be an instance.

```
$this->authorize('show', [$auction, $product]);
```